# Convert System.Net.Mail.Message to EWS Email?

Tags: email, exchangewebservices, message

Is there a simple Way to convert a System.Net.Mail.Message Object to Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessage (EWS)? Or is the only way to build a new one? (i want to Add a new Feature sending Mails trough EWS to my app, currently it uses SMTP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't convert them because they are two completely different classes (from different assemblies) and they also use two different protocols eg one is using SMTP and one is using SOAP. So you would be better to just rewrite your Send function.

One thing you can do with EWS if you have MIMEContent is to send that MIME content eg

```
        EmailMessage Message = new EmailMessage(service);
        Message.MimeContent = new MimeContent("UTF-8", baByteArray);
        Message.SendAndSaveCopy();
```

but AFAIK System.Net.Mail.Message doesn't give you the ability to export to MIME like the old CDO classes used to.